# Optionally runtime properties

Tags: design-patterns, c++

I’m looking for information on a pattern that I have used recently. The basic idea is that there is a type with a property that can either be compile-time (template parameter) or runtime (member). [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) is a good example of this pattern. Here is an example of the pattern in its purest form:

```
// sentinel value
constexpr int runtime = -1;

// compile-time version
template <int Property = runtime>
struct Type {
  static constexpr int getProp() {
    return Property;
  }
};

// runtime version
template <>
struct Type<runtime> {
  int getProp() const {
    return property;
  }
private:
  int property;
};

template <typename T>
int square(T obj) {
  // does a multiply if T is Type<runtime>
  // otherwise returns a constant
  return obj.getProp() * obj.getProp();
}
```

You usually end up with two very similar classes so I typically hoist common code up into a base class using the CRTP idiom.

- Does this pattern have a name?
- If there isn’t a good name, how should I describe it? (The title of the question is my best attempt)
- Has someone written about this pattern somewhere?
- When should I avoid using this pattern?

Comment: [Convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) possibly?  That's more of a design paradigm though rather than a pattern though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll be only referring to *'When should I avoid using this pattern?'*:

I tend to say *'always'*:

1. There's a sentinel value (in given case -1) – what if you need it at compile time? Then you'd still have to use the runtime variant.
2. Any two of `Type<n>` with differing values for `n` are different, independent types. So if you intended to use them together in a container – bad luck. But if you cannot, then what's use case for?

So instead of specialising one special (sentinel) value, I'd go with two totally unrelated classes:

```
template <int Property>
struct CompileTimeType
{
    static constexpr int getProp() { return Property; }
};
struct RunTimeType
{
    int getProp() const { return property; }
private:
    int property;
};
```

Be aware that as is now, you'd have to use both differently anyway:

```
CompileTimeType<whatEver>::getProp();
RuntimeType rtt;
rtt.getProp();
```

All no problem if you know in advance what type you have. Want to use them in template functions? Well, one time, you need an instance, the other time not. Hmm... – Still want to have an instance for compile time variant as well? Then you can make the function non-static.

If you want to combine arbitrary combinations of comtile and run time instances in a container, you'd need a common base class anyway (even for different compile time instanciations, not considering the run time variant...). Then you'd be *forced* to have non-static functions in all variants. But the virtual function call you introduce this way will consume up all advantages you gained previously by template usage, so you could as well stay with the runtime variant only then and likely are even better off...

Comment: “What if you need the sentinel at compile time”. How often do you need an array with a size of -1?

Comment: “You can’t store different compile time versions in a container” If you need runtime polymorphism, use the runtime version.

Comment: “You can’t pass around an instance of the compile time version”. You wouldn’t typically store just a single property in a class like this.  std::span  stores a runtime pointer and a runtime or compile time size. std::array stores runtime elements and a compile time size. You can call a static function like this compileTimeInstance.getProp(). This means that you can pass either the runtime or compile time version to a template function.

Comment: You could pass either a std::array or a std::vector to a template function and it will just work.

Comment: @Kerndog73 1. Where did you ever speak of arrays? The question was more general. 2. But you don't need a template specialisation for, have a *separate* class. 3. Have a close look: `std::span`and `std::array` both have one single template parameter for the type. As mentioned, `Type<10>` and `Type<12>` are different types, you cannot place both of them into the same array. Do you want all of your configuration objects to return the *same* value? 4. see 3.

Comment: @Kerndog73 What you *could* do, though: pass all the different objects to a variadic template function. But for this, again, you don't need the runtime version to be a specialisation, you can have the separate class again, as long as it provides the same interface as the templates (keyword ["duck typing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)).

Comment: @Kerndog73 There might be one single exception: `template <int n> void f(Type<n>);` vs. `template <typename T> void f(T& t)` The latter would allow any other type providing a `getProp` function, whereas the former would prevent it. But I don't see much benefit in preventing, though - if the user has his/her own *compatible* type, why not allow to use it?

Comment: A specialization *is a separate class*. When you specialize a template class, you define the whole thing. The difference is that you get a better name. std::runtime_span and std::compile_time_span sound a bit clunky. That's really the whole point of using this pattern: better names. Also, I'm using this pattern in a 2D array class where the dimensions of the array can either be specified at compile-time or runtime. All of the functions that manipulate the 2D arrays are templates that don't care what kind of 2D arrays they're dealing with. I think we're both talking about different use cases.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Admitted, my wording was not precise... Sure, the specialisation *is* a separate class as well, but considering the sample in my answer, I assumed it'd be clear what I meant... About the arrays: `Type<7> config[12][10];` What's the use case for all objects returning the same value?

Comment: @Kerndog73 More consistent naming *might* be an argument, but the disadvantages outweigh the advantages (well, admitted, my point of view).

Comment: I never mentioned configuration of any kind. We're talking about different things.

Comment: A set of multiple properties might form a configuration. But that's not the issue. I'm referring to the question as presented. By the way: CRTP is not possible with this class: `template <typename T> class B {}; class D : B<D> {};` - you need a type template parameter for. Maybe your example does not match the use case? May be you want to be more explicit about...

Comment: Hm, comparing your example to std::span you cited as well, I get the impression your example was minimalised a bit too much and you have something far more general in mind. Is it?

Comment: [Here is the real code that this question was based apon](https://github.com/Kerndog73/Simpleton-Engine/blob/master/Simpleton/Grid/grid.hpp). CRTP *is* possible with this class. `GridBase` is the CRTP base. There's a compile-time version `Grid<int, 4, 2>` and a runtime version `Grid<int>`. [Here are some template functions that don't care what they're dealing with](https://github.com/Kerndog73/Simpleton-Engine/blob/master/Simpleton/Grid/transform.inl).

Comment: Still think two independent classes (template compiletime + non-template runtime) are better approach. For your functions: `template <typename T> T flip_x(T const& in) { T out(in.size()); /* ... */ }` still does the trick. Problem only with `transpose`, as you (potentially) need to return a *different* type. But that is solved easily: Have another alias `TransposedType` in the then template and non-template classes, then you'd have: `template <typename T> typename T::TransposedType transpose(T const& t)` (pre-C++11 compatible; alternatively with auto and optionally trailing return type).

Comment: Additionally, as negative sizes are meaningless, I'd then change the template parameters to `size_t`. By the way: As data is stored in an internal array, move construction and assignment still need to copy the data (won't be a problem in your functions presented due to guaranteed copy elision since C++17, but if you do so on other occasions, this might get an issue).

Comment: Using `T` and `T::TransposedType` would certainly make those functions a little cleaner. Using `std::array` in the compile-time version may not be a good idea. However, it was a good idea for the situation where I was using this class. `Grid<char, 4, 4>` is just 16 bytes.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Depends... If you create objects once, pass them around via reference or pointer, then you're better off with internal array, as for accessing, you spare one level of indirection. Your sample functions: great chance of getting [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/how-to-return-an-object-from-a-function-considering-c11-rvalues-and-move-seman), but as NRVO, not *guaranteed*. For guarantee, you need to do the stuff in a constructor, e. g. `return T(in, operation_tag_class);` (overloads) or `return T<OpEnum::Which>(in);`, if willing to specialise constructors.

Comment: `std::span` and `std::string_view` are view-like classes. This is not a minor detail, and is deeply relevant to this discussion. Suppose we have two view-like classes that are highly compatible, with the only exception that one of them provides more compile-time information. Do we need to provide overloaded functions if we want to accept them as function arguments? No. The view variant with more compile-time information (the more specialized one) can simply implicitly return (convert into) a flyweight copy of the other view variant if needed to. Classes with ownership can't do this easily.